# For powershell executing another powershell, what's the difference between "&" and "."

Tags: powershell, execution

Like:

```
& another.ps1
```

And

```
. another.ps1
```

What's their difference?
I wish to take the output text of another powershell script, while not wanting to import the internal functions defined in the other script. What statement can I use? I found even "&" command will automatically import all function definitions of the other powershell script.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see that effect at all with respect to functions. They are not visible with the call operator ("&"), but they are visible when using the dot source operator (".").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is scope.  `&` will run the script in it's own scope.  `.` will run the script in the current scope.

```
$ErrorView = 'CategoryView'
$x = 'Test'

. { Get-variable x -Scope 0 }
& { Get-Variable x -Scope 0 }


Name                           Value                                                                      
----                           -----                                                                      
x                              Test                                                                       
ObjectNotFound: (x:String) [Get-Variable], ItemNotFoundException
```

In first example, the script is dot-sourced into the current scope, and $x is visible at Scope 0.

In the second example, the script is invoked with the & operator and $x is not visible at Scope 0.